# MYSQL bulkinsert: multi insert with value into a select

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I have a question about the multi-ing (bulk) insert with mysql..

I know that:

```
INSERT INTO "my_table" ('col1','col2','col3') VALUES 
(1,1,1),(2,2,2);
```

But I need to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO "my_table" ('col1','col2','col3') VALUES
((SELECT select1 as col1,select2 as col3 from "my_table2"),"textForAllCol2")
```

Where my select return a list of 2 column.

I'M trying to explain the best i can..

Thanks for your help!

JP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is referenced [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de003/1) for you

Modify your query as

```
INSERT INTO my_table SELECT col1, "textForAllCol2", col2 FROM my_table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
INSERT INTO "my_table" ('col1','col2','col3')
SELECT select1, "textForAllCol2", select2 from my_table2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    INSERT INTO my_table (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`)
    SELECT select1, "textForAllCol2", select2 from my_table2
```

Answer (score 0):

If your source and destination columns names are related (even partially) with each other, I prefer to use aliases for readability:

```sql
    INSERT INTO my_table (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`)
    SELECT `col1`, "textForAllCol2" as `col2`, `select3` as `col3` from my_table2
```